# Modal, modeless divs on a page

Tags: javascript, xhtml, html

I'm using modal, modeless `div`s (I mean fixed, styled `div`s) on my HTML page. This page contains `iframe`s with modal `div`s as well.

When I open a new `div` on the page, I need to disable keyboard events on the parent page (opener page). Also I need to be able to handle tab key presses on the parent page. 
I have Googled, but I haven't found any solution for solving this issue.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: I think you're confusing the meaning of "modal" and "modeless". Something cannot be both at the same time.

Comment: Modal, Modeless just a meaning, i think you missunderstood, i wrote [modal, modeless divs (I mean fixed, styled divs)] :

Let me explain;
You have 2 div on the page and your page contain any information, for examle blog entires list page. 
1st div z-index value is 10000 and position:fixed;opacity:0.5 
2nd div z-index value is 10001 and position:fixed and this div contain a iframe then navigate any sub page on the site;

When you opened both divs on the page, it seems modal. if you can try to remove 1st div from the page, it seems modeless window now. 

I mean that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) with [this plugin](http://jshotkeys.googlepages.com/test-static-01.html) could help you? Keybinding is made simple, and to disable a key (ex CTRL+F) you simply write:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'Ctrl-f', function(evt) {return false;});
```

Comment: i'm already using jquery in my solution, but i haven't found any solution.